# $* d * $ operator --- Digest the (differential/geometry) meaning

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, yang-mills, classical-field-theory

I like to digest better:

- the $* d * $ operator in Maxwell differential form equation
- the $* D * $ operator in Yang-Mills differential form equation

We already knew that in Maxwell differential form equation we have: 
$$
* d * F=0
$$
knew that in Yang-Mills differential form equation we have:
$$
* D * F=0
$$
here $D .=d .+ [A,.]$

> But how we do understand  $* d * $ operator and $* D * $ operator? Their  the (differential/geometry) meaning? How do we make ourselves comfortable , even though we also knew the equation boils down to:

$$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu}=0
$$
$$
D_\mu F^{\mu \nu}=0
$$
respectively. But how to think $* d * $ operator and $* D * $ operator differential/geometry-ly?

Comment: Well, do you understand what $\ast$ and $d$ individually mean?